# Can unit tests be implemented effectively with agile development?

Tags: unit-testing, tdd, agile

Soon I will be involved in a project that will be using the agile project management/development approach, with 5 (or so) 2 week sprints. The project will be using a DDD design pattern which I have found in the past works great with unit testing, hence I have enthusiasim to use it for this project as well. The only problem is given the following factors I am unsure as to whether unit testing can be successfully implemented with agile development:

- Potential for constantly changing requirements (requirements change, tests break, tests need to be updated too).
- Time factor (unit tests can make dev take a fair bit longer and if requirements change towards the end of a sprint there may be too little time to update tests and production code at the best quality).

I have a feeling that if/when requirements change (especially if towards the end of a sprint) and given the tight deadlines unit tests will become a burden. Anyone have any good advice on the matter?

Comment: This question is off-topic because it's not within the scope for this site, as defined in [What topics can I ask about here?](//stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Also see: [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](//stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask) You may be able to ask on [another Stack Exchange site](//stackexchange.com/sites#name), *perhaps* [pm.se] or [softwareengineering.se]. Be sure to read the help center's on-topic page for any site on which you intend to post a question.

Comment: @Makyen This question was posted over 7 years ago when these other exchanges didn't exist/weren't well known about or the boundries weren't clearly defined... so, uh.. thanks for the info? What a weird update.

Comment: @Makyen are you literally going through the oldest of the old posts and giving advice based on the current set of FAQs? You have a long road ahead of you my friend!

Comment: I'm going through the close-vote-review queue. I'm not picking the questions from the site. But, rather than use one of the canned reasons, which, while potentially also applicable, gives an inaccurate impression that the question could be made to be on-topic by editing it, I'm using a custom reason that actually explains that the question isn't on topic for the site. Using a custom reason results in that reason being posted as a comment, as above. I look at doing so as being honest and straightforward about the situation.

Comment: Yes, at one time this question may have been on-topic. What's on-topic for Stack Overflow has changed over the years. It's now off-topic. That should not reflect badly upon you. It's just how the site has changed.

Comment: @Makyen Fair dues

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think it cuts both ways. On one hand, yes, unit tests are extra code which requires extra maintenance, and will slow you down a bit. On the other hand, if requirements start evolving, having unit tests in place will be a life saver in making sure what you are changing still works.

Comment: Your second point is the most important in my books. Being able to change things safe in the knowledge that the rest of the system still works makes it much easier to make those changes.

Comment: I don't think TDD is very controversial. Most people agree that unit testing takes time but helps development (and that usually the benefit outweigh the costs), but not everyone is convinced that writing the tests first is helpful. Writing tests first has value as a design process, but it doesn't work for everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Considering 10+ weeks worth of code with no test coverage makes me cringe. When will you have time to manually test all that code? And under evolving requirements, you will use a lot more time tracking down impacts the changes will have throughout your code base.

I cannot advice strongly enough to use unit testing. Even when doing DDD, let unit tests drive implementation. Coupled with good patterns like DI/IoC and SRP, you should find both your code base and tests to be more resilient to change, and thus save you a lot of time throughout those sprints.

Comment: I work in projects that take years and have no test coverage. Not that I like it. Not at all.

Comment: @Peri - I feel sorry for you, and sadly, many projects are like that. Hopefully not too many greenfield projects start out skimping on automated testing. It is not too late though, I've been handed systems with 0% coverage and been able to yank it up to 50%, gradually testing pieces as they've gone through new changes.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you have unit tests with high coverage, the cost of change will grow exponentially as the projects moves forward. So basically, the more change you anticipate the MORE you will actually need your unit tests.

Secondly, good unit tests depend on very few and small feature pieces in your production code. When this is true, only a few tests will be impacted when a feature changes. Basically, each test tests just one thing and small piece of production code. The key to writing unit tests that follow this principle is to decouple your code and test in isolation.

Thirdly, you need to get a better understanding of the concept of DONE and why its definition is so important in terms of sustainable development. Basically, you can't go fast over time in a sustainable fashion if your team compromizes the concept of DONE in the short term.